# unable to serve json file with express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

i have a few questions:

i am building an app with angular and node (Express).

1)
in my node server i am serving all static files in my static_dir

```
app.use(express.static(STATIC_DIR));
```

insdie this dir i have a json file static_Dir/courts/courts.json

my controll is as follows:

```
squashApp.controller('CourtsController',
    function CourtsController($scope) {
    //$http.get('courts/courts.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.courts = 'courts/courts.json';
  });
```

and my html file is:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Hour</th>
      <th>Player 1</th>
      <th>Player 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>itai</td>
      <td>asf</td>
      <td>sdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="court in courts">
      <td>{{court.hour}}</td>
      <td>{{court.player1}}</td>
      <td>{{court.player2}}</td>
    </tr>
```

for some reason the information on this json file isn't showing in my table.
what is the reason?

another issue regarding unit tests and jasmin:

my test:

```
describe('controllers', function(){

  it('should create courts model', (function() {
    var scope = {},
    ctrl = new squashApp.controller.CourtsController(scope);
    expect(scope.courts.length).toBe(6)
  }));

});
```

but i am getting an erro that CourtsController is not defined.
what should be the correct syntax in order to make the test work.

thanks.

Comment: does angular handle filesystem reads for you?

Answer (score -2):

```
var path = require('path');
...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and

```
/courts/courts.json
```

Comment: the didn't really fix anything